# Indirect questions nested inside phrases

Tags: questions, particle-か, interrogatives

Trying to use interrogative words in nested (indirect ?) questions has been troublesome for me.

First came things like:

> 先生が何を言ったか知らない

Which I guess means "I don´t know what the teacher said". So far, so good.

However, I have been looking into using と for quotations, or for reporting to a whole phrase.

For example:

> 彼はこれは何だと言ったか

Which I think means "What did he say this is ?"

But what if I just wanted to know if he said this is something or not, like: "Did he say this is something, or didn´t he say it ?"

Would it be something like this ? (below)

> 彼は「これは何か」と言ったかどうか?

Lastly, if I wanted to say "Do you remember what he said this is ?", would it be:

> 彼はこれは何だと言ったか覚えていますか?

If there is anything wrong with my guessed meanings, please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

彼はこれは何だと言ったか is not a complete sentence but a clause that's embedded in a sentence like 彼は（自分が）これは何だと言ったか覚えていなかった："He didn't remember what he said it was".

"Did he say this is something, or didn´t he say it ?"  is expressed as あの人、これ が(/を) 何（か）だとか言ってた？ それとも言ってなかった？（or …言ってませんでしたか？） or so. Using 言っていた instead of 言った is another point. (This is difficult to explain, though)

彼は「これは何か」と言ったかどうか is not a complete sentence either, but a clause as in "He didn't remember **if** he said "what's this" **or not**".

彼はこれは何だと言ったか覚えていますか? more likely means "Does he remember what I/you/he said this is?" than "Do you remember what he said this is?". If you want to make it clear, the latter should be 彼**が** これ は(/が) 何だと言ったか覚えていますか.

Comment: thanks for the corrections. Using Xとか。。。　was new to me, but I think I get the gist of it. Secondly, 言ってた　over 言った isn´t just a question of formality ? Lastly, if my phrases are "incomplete sentences" (which for sure made sense), then how can I convey the meaning I wanted ("What did he say this is ?") ?

Comment: ? Are you there ?

Comment: @VitorArruda 1) 言ってた is 言っていた, not a simple past. 2) "What did he say this is?" is 彼はこれ（が／は／を）何だと言ってた？ or ～言ってましたか？.

Answer (score 0):

What you guess is totally good but one:

> Did he say this is something, or didn't he say it ?"
>
> 彼は「これは何か」と言ったかどうか?

This Japanese sentence may be received as "Did he ask what this is?"

I think it is hard to exactly express it, but my best answer is:

> 彼はこれを何かだと言ったか？

The point is だ after 何か. Here 何かだ is expected to be received as "being something", but not somewhat "being what".

Of course there is a better way to do almost the same, if you don't stick to say it literally. For example:

> 彼はこれについて何か言ってましたか。

Comment: ＠Faily Feely, I understand the need for か　in 何かだ. However, why これを何。。。 instead of これは何。。。?

Comment: Sorry, I unconsciously did that, avoiding two uses of は in a row. 彼はこれ**は**何かだと言ったか？ is still fine, but 彼はこれ**を**何かだと言ったか？ sounds a little bit better. 　 AをBと言う means something like "say that A is B", here A is これ and B is 何かだ. So, を and は are almost interchangeable here.